# OOM Error when loading Drawable

Tags: android, image

My Image has the size: 2480px x 3508px. I know that this is a very big image for android and so I try to resize it.

I'm using the PhotoView library too by the way.

Here i start resize the Image:

```
Drawable resizedDrawable = resize(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.handskizze), 50, 50);
skizze.setImageDrawable(resizedDrawable);
mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(skizze);
```

The method which resizes the drawable:

```
private Drawable resize (Drawable image, int dstWith, int dstHeight) {
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,dstWith,dstHeight,false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmapResized);
}
```

The Error:

```
            at de.example.app.TouchMoveImage.onCreate(TouchMoveImage.java:70)
```

So why i can't resize the Image? I know that is it to big for android. But it crashes before it starts resizing.

Comment: use `BitmapFactory#decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)`

Comment: where do i have to use this?